# Video Card is not being recognized

Tags: graphics-card, bios, computer-building

This is a newly built computer tower
So far i have checked the device manager, which does not show my video card, i have tried another video card, which didn't show up either, BIOS SATA mode is on PCIe
This determines that the video card isn't bad if the other one wasn't showing up either, but they were receiving power as the fans on both of them were spinning, it couldn't be the motherboard unless by some act of god, both PCIe slots are defective and everything else is working fine, i tried disabling the on-board video memory which did nothing. All drivers for the motherboard are installed, all updates for windows 7 downloaded. The disk that came with the graphics card will not load drivers. it starts to scan for hardware and says "no graphics hardware detected" though that is not what it says word for word, just something like that. As of right now there is nothing i can do because my friend who is a computer engineer has the tower and is looking at it but even he is hitting dead ends. What could possibly be causing this wild error. Finally when the computer is booting up i get an "IDE detect" error on the motherboard, and occasionally a "SCSI detect" error as well.

Comment: the second video card used to determine if the video card was at fault was a known working video card fyi.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your monitor displays images correctly when your monitor is plugged into the newly inserted video card (e.g. BIOS post, Windows' 640x480 256-color mode), it's just that Windows won't recognise it?

The "IDE detect" and "SCSI detect" errors might be indicative of a pending motherboard fault - you might have bad capacitors or some other component is failing that would be affecting the PCI-Exppress bus (which explains why both slots aren't working properly for you).

So based on the information you've provided - I'm going to assume your motherboard is dying. If it's still under warranty then you should be fine to get a replacement.

Comment: i will take the bad capacitors into consideration. If the capacitors are bad, would a continuity test with a multimeter help determine that issue. As for the graphics card, the monitor acts as if it isn't plugged into anything when plugged into the graphics card through either DVI or VGA, i have had to use the on-board video to use it and do things such as viewing the device manager.

Comment: Did you disable the on-board graphics entirely (not just the memory, as you describe)? Some older motherboards (certainly not new ones) might disable all secondary cards if the built-in graphics are enabled (this was true in the days of AGP). I wouldn't think you could diagnose a faulty capacitor without an extremely technical knowledge of the motherboard (and its service manual, if one exists at all).

Comment: i disabled it in the device manager and the screen resolution goes all out of wack. i then shut it down, plugged into the graphics card and turned back on, but to no avail. This is a brand new extremely high end motherboard.

Comment: asrock z68 extreme3 gen3

Comment: video card - asus gtx 550 Ti 1600Mhz.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a common issue with the AsRock boards.  I have a new AsRock z68 Extreme4 Gen3, and my PCIe 1 bus appears to be completely dead.  I'm returning my mobo tomorrow.